# Use external help file for C# programmed powershell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I now have .cs file for a powershell cmdlet in C#.  And I have an XML file as the external help file for the cmdlet.  How can I link these two?

For powershell script, I can use `.ExternalHelp` keyword in comment-based help.  But for a cmdlet programmed in C#, how can I achieve the same effect?

Comment: So you want to read the XML file in C#?

Comment: You need to provide the correct files in the correct place relative to your binary module, as described here: [Writing Help for PowerShell Modules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/help/writing-help-for-windows-powershell-modules?view=powershell-7).  For easier maintainance of the help files, take a look at [PlatyPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/create-help-using-platyps?view=powershell-7)

Comment: @boxdog so I don't need to modify C# source code and just have to name the xml file in the correct format?